# Modify the Cantor pairing function

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

I have an infinite set of pairs $I:=\{(k,m) \mid k,m \in \mathbb{N},\quad m\geq 1, \quad 1\leq k\leq m\}$.

I want to establish a bijective correspondence $\phi$ between $I$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

I've already looked up the Cantor's pairing function, but here I have to pay attention that $k\leq m$: so I have to modify the original Cantor function.

The problem is that all the functions I tried aren't injective, I've tried for example:

$$\phi(k,m)=\frac{(k+m)(|k-m|+1)}{2}\quad\text{but }\phi(1,2)=\phi(3,3)=3$$

Any ideas?

And given the right fuction, how can I find the inverse function to show that it is bijective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map

$$\varphi:I\to\Bbb Z^+:\langle k,m\rangle\mapsto\frac{m(m-1)}2+k$$

will work. There are $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i=\frac{m(m-1)}2$ ordered pairs in $I$ with second coordinate less than $m$, so the $k$-th pair with second coordinate $m$ is the $\left(\frac12m(m-1)+k\right)$-th pair in the reverse lexicographic order on $I$.

Comment: This works! So it's not necessary that the function is symmetric, I was wrong.

Comment: How can I invert this function to show that it is bijective?

Comment: @Nat: You don’t need to invert it to show that it’s bijective. Note that $$\frac{(m+1)m}2-\frac{m(m-1)}2=m\;,$$ so $\varphi(\langle 1,m+1\rangle)=\varphi(\langle m,m\rangle)+1$: there’s no overlap between the integers $\varphi(\langle k,m\rangle)$ with $1\le k\le m$ and the integers $\varphi(\langle k,m+1\rangle)$ with $1\le k\le m+1$.